# Gezeira of Rabbeinu Gershom History

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, jewish-books, text, cherem

Has the original text of the Gazeira of Rabbeinu Gershom been lost.  If so when?  Who are the earliest sources stating such?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4901/gezeira-of-rabbeinu-gershom-text

Answer (score 2):

The late professor Louis Finkelstein writes extensively on this topic in his work Jewish self-government in the middle ages ([pdf](http://sammlungen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/urn/urn:nbn:de:hebis:30-180014881001)), see especially starting on page 111.

His answer is that it is unclear if all the takkanot which are attributed to him originated with R' Gershom to begin with and that the original text has certainly been lost. He attempts to reconstruct the language from various sources he lists ad loc.

Comment: I would humbly add that his book is the authoritative source for study of R. Gershom's enactments and others of the Middle Ages.

Answer (score 1):

The answer  [here](http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/hssample.pdf) in the Footnotes of Halachically Speaking, Volume 5 Issue 17, "Reading Another Person's Letter"

Comment: Which footnote are you referring to?

Comment: all of the first paragraph footnotes brings down who talks about it

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20241&st=&pgnum=21

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20241&st=&pgnum=22

(וכן העיד הרא"ש:"ותקנותיו וגזרותיו קבועות ותקועות כאילו נתנו מסיני" (שו"ת הרא"ש כלל מ"ג סימן 
ח'

Comment: That addresses the issue of their acceptance, but what about the text issue?

Comment: @Yosef - the link gives you the earliest sources that mention the Cherem.