# Question about Polygamy and Marriage Ceremonies

Tags: history, marriage, wedding

This is a follow up to [my previous question on Polygamy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11040/questions-about-polygamy-in-jewish-law-and-culture)

In Jewish marriages, was it ever common for a man to marry more than one wife in the same ceremony?

---

The context: I've been looking into polygamy in general, and [there's a parable where Jesus talks about 10 virgins (linked to H.SE Question)](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/406/are-the-ten-virgins-told-in-jesus-parable-multiple-brides-or-just-general-wed/441), and some argue that this means that all of them are being married at the same time to one person.

I'm hoping some of you can shed some light on this. Thank you!

Comment: Yaaov had to wait a week before marrying Leah.
Vayetze 29:27
http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?AID=9173&p=complete&showrashi=true

Comment: Regardless of the answer to your question, the answer to your real question is that those 10 virgins are not 10 brides. In the Talmud it talks about how the virgins would dance in the fields on Yom Kippur and other places it talks about how they accompany the bride on her wedding day.

Comment: @avi: Do you know if there is a copy of that part of the Talmud online?  It would be helpful for us to be able to source on the BH.SE question.  (If not, I suppose we could just source your comment. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson hope this helps  http://books.google.com/books?id=AdziebDqjY4C&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=Talmud+virgins+dancing+white+yom+kippur&source=bl&ots=QIw0urVMfk&sig=hNrpm5YEMccI1hSEK71QCLU5M1w&hl=en&ei=-NGyTpCAEsOd-wbfhdX3Aw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Kesubos 93b discusses a man who married three women in the same day.

Answer (score 6):

It is permitted to do so in principle, provided that afterwards the husband sets aside individual time to rejoice with each wife (Maimonides' Mishneh Torah, [Laws of Marriage 10:13](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952884/jewish/Chapter-Ten.htm)). Considering that polygamy itself was uncommon, though, it's doubtful that this law was applied in practice.

Comment: However later authorities advised against marrying two women simultaneously. It's discussed at length in a responsum by the 20th century authority Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, regarding doing a double ceremony for two sisters (marrying *different* husbands!)