# Is there an equivalent of the sotah for men?

Tags: sotah-secluded-woman

We know a woman accused of adultery has to drink the sotah water to prove her innocence

In a case where she is guilty, what happens to the man she was with? What is the punishment for a man who commits adultery with a married woman?

Comment: Just to clarify: Men are allowed to have multiple wives according to Torah law. The question is if a woman can warn her husband against secluding himself with an already-married woman?

Comment: related (duplicate?): [In adultery, why is a wife is guilty, and a husband not?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33477/11501)

Comment: what about a married man being secluded with a married woman?

Comment: If you have a clarification to your question, please [edit] it into the question post instead of relegating it to comments. Comments are ephemeral by design and may disappear at any time.

Comment: @Lilopinpin A man can have multiple wives. There is no difference between a married man and an unmarried man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent of Sotah for men.  Also, the sotah procedure was discontinued by Rabban Yohanan Ben Zakkai because too many men were adulterers (see the Mishna in Sotah 47a).

Comment: Also, when there was a Sotah procedure, when the woman drank, if she was guilty her paramour also blew up.

Comment: And to flesh out Maurice's answer a bit more -- if the husband is running around misbehaving, all bets are off, the procedure doesn't work.