# According to Jewish sources: is polygyny kosher to practice?

Tags: halacha

There was (but now expired) ban on practicing polygyny among Ashkenazim, but there never was a ban among Sephardim. Do Jewish texts or rabbinic sources provide any definitive anti-response or pro-response in regards to polygyny for today? Polygyny was practiced widely among our forefathers, from Abraham downward.

Comment: very related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11040/questions-about-polygamy-in-jewish-law-and-culture

Comment: This source http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/558598/jewish/Does-Jewish-Law-Forbid-Polygamy.htm states polygyny is "ALMOST [emphasis mine]non-existent" among Sephardic Jews today. I suspect though that the frequency may be higher since some Haredim get married under the chuppah but don't register their marriages with the state.

Comment: i follow up on your appropriate additional comment. for what halachic purpose, if any, does "register[ing] ... marriages with the state" serve? why do something that is not even required under halacha or tanakh? registering a marriage with the modern state, any modern state, is a nice legal way to say, please register so that we may ALSO tax your marriage!