# Is there a reason in Kabbalah that G-d permitted polygamy?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

Is there an explanation in the Kabbalah as to why the Torah allows Polygamy?

Comment: I heard something in a shiur once. I can't remember it exactly. It was something along the lines of Yaacov's neshama was divided 5 ways, and 4 of those ways were his wives, and each brought a different aspect (Leah brought the "tears" of teshuva, for example). It might follow from this that those aspects' energy was huge then, and needed an entire person to bring it to the world, but nowadays, a single person can bring what's necessary to the marriage and so we only marry one, which has always been the ideal.

Comment: I have read the same

Comment: I have heard the same

Comment: Why wouldn't the Torah allow polygamy (or specifically polygyny)? It is only allowed, not recommended.

Comment: Why allow it if there's no mitzvah in it

Answer (score 2):

From the Zohar below I think we can give an answer as to why Hashem permitted Polygamy:

> > זוהר חלק ב דף רנו/ב: ורזא דמלה, יעקב נטיל ארבע נשין, וכליל לון בגויה,
> > ואף על גב דאוקימנא להאי מלה ברזא אחרא, דאיהו קיימא בין תרין עלמין,
> > ורזא דכלא, כד יעקב נטיל האי היכלא דאיהו שתיתאה, נטיל וכליל בגוויה כל
> > אינון ארבע נשין, ארבע מלאכין, וכלהו דבקי בהיכלא דא, אלין אינון ארבע
> > רישי נהרין, דכתיב )בראשית ב י( ומשם יפרד והיה לארבעה ראשים, אלין ארבע
> > רישין, אינון ארבע נשין דנטיל לון יעקב, ונטיל היכלא דא.
> >
> > “The secret of the matter: Ya’acov took four wives and included them
> > within him. Though we explained it through another mystery, NAMELY,
> > that he stands between two worlds OF ATZILUT, CALLED ‘RACHEL AND
> > LEAH;’ NEVERTHELESS, the secret of the whole matter is that when
> > Ya’acov took this chamber, the sixth one, he included in it these four
> > women, who were four angels, all attached to this chamber. These are
> > the four sources of the rivers, as it is written, “and from thence it
> > was parted, and branched into four streams” (Bereishit 2:10). These
> > four branches are the four women Ya’acov married, who took this
> > chamber (Zohar 2,156b).
>
> The Zohar explains that the souls of Rachel, Leah, Zilpah, and Bilhah,
> were really four parts of one soul, called “Rachel.” This concurs with
> the tradition that all four were sisters. Rachel and Leah were even
> twins (Seder Olam Rabbah 2). The rectification of creation requires
> the reunification of all four parts into one soul. This is similar to
> how Ya’acov absorbed Esav into his being by first buying the
> birthright, and then receiving the blessings. The four holy wives of
> Ya’acov represent Ya’acov’s mission in the world to unify all these
> elements and thus rectify Adam, whose sin caused the fragmentation of
> the world. For the sake of this lofty rectification, Ya’acov had to
> marry four wives and deviate from the command not to marry two
> sisters. By joining together with one husband and overcoming the
> natural tendency of rivalry, Ya’acov’s four holy wives became as one
> unified person, enacting the highest tikun of creation.”

(Translation and explanation from https://www.berotbatayin.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/VayetzePolygamy.pdf)

I think that based on the Zohar we can maybe say that Adam's sin refers to two things: 1) the Eitz Hadaat, 2) How he wasted seed and caused all the demons and evil spirits to enter the world (Eruvin 18b). The message could be that are job was is rectify the sin of the eitz hadaat and was also to rectify the sin of Adam’s wasting seed, by having more than one wife in order to produce more Jews (since the Gemera in Brachot 6a says demons are more numerous than we are) who cause rectification and not destruction. To perform Torah and mitzvot, and not harm and kill people (Midrash Rabah Naso 12, Ibn Ezra Vakira 17, Brachot 43a). The reason Polygamy was prohibited Rabbinically was because people were causing more problems than rectifications (see here: [When and why did we get rid of polygamy?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69102/when-and-why-did-we-get-rid-of-polygamy/69112#69112) for @sabbahillel who gives many reasons why polygamy is forbidden).

This is just a thought and answer that is possible. Hope it makes some sense :)

Comment: Great answer! I'm not sure you can say polygamy was prohibited miderabanan, at least not for all of klal Yisrael

Comment: @יהושעק, thanks! What type of prohibition was it, if not a derabbanan? And who in Klal Yisrael is an exception to this?

Comment: My pleasure, Avishai! Check out the answers here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11040/questions-about-polygamy-in-jewish-law-and-culture