# What are the 3 things Rabeinu Gershom banned?

Tags: halacha, history, rabbis, cherem

I've heard that Rabeinu Gershom (a 10th-11th century scholar) banned 3 things, and I know one of them is polygamy. Does anyone know what the other two are?

Comment: Why do you say there are 3? (You're right, of course, but a source would be nice to boost the value of your question. The other two of the 'famous three' are divorcing your wife against her will, and opening others' mail. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershom_ben_Judah#Synod_and_bans)

Comment: @DoubleAA, per the Be'er HaGolah (brought in [Gershon's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18867/5)), there are more than 3.

Comment: @SethJ Hence my `'famous three'`. It might be interesting to determine what set these three aside historically.

Comment: See [Kol Bo siman 116](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15217&st=&pgnum=363&hilite=)

Answer (score 16):

[Be'er Hagolah at the end of Yoreh Deah 334](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=336) lists the following:

- Not to marry more than 1 wife.
- Someone who is in Cherem should not be a Shaliach Tzibur.
- A person should not be away from his wife more than 18 months.
- Not to rent a house from a non Jew if a Jew is living there.
- Not to cut off the margin of a page of a Sefer, even to write on it.
- Not to embarrass a Baal Teshuva about his previous sins.
- Not to look at his friends letters without permission.

There are many more, see the link above.

Comment: How is embarassing a Baal Teshuva not Ona'at Devarim mideoraita already? See Mishna BM 4 10: אם היה בעל תשובה לא יאמר לו זכור מעשיך הראשונים

Comment: (follow up question here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18868/759)

Comment: "D" is mentioned as a Takanah, btw.

Comment: "G" also has a qualifier that I've never heard anyone mention before. Thanks for providing the link, because I think some of these are misunderstood. (Even more reason for [this other question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4901/5) to be asked.)

Comment: at the end of the list the Be'er Hagolah writes that he copied the list from the Teshuvat Maharam, who lists additional gezerot, not brought by the Be'er Hagolah due to lack of space.

Comment: >Not to cut off the margin of a page of a Sefer, even to write on it. What does that mean

Answer (score 4):

I have heard that he wrote all of sha"s and said that that is the authoritative girsa and was gozer not the change it.

(from sefer פירושי רבינו גרשום printed by אור החיים, in the הקדמה)

Comment: from sefer פירושי רבינו גרשום printed by אור החיים, in the הקדמה.

Comment: Is there a reason you put your source in a comment and not in the answer?

Comment: Sorry for my illiteracy what does sha"s stand for?