# Must seforim be printed with margins?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, jewish-books, writing-printing

I have heard that there is a halacha that seforim must be printed with margins, so that scholars will be able to write notes on their learning.

Is there any source for this?

If this is not in fact accurate, is there a similar halacha that may have been misunderstood to mean this?

Comment: Torah scrolls need margins but not for this reason

Comment: @DoubleAA Sounds like an answer to the last question.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be the cherem of Rabbeinu Gershom https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18867

Comment: Pretty sure this is not accurate.